# Why docker-compose don't let me create a volume?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am writing this request today because I will like to create my first Docker container. I watched a lot of tutorials, and there I come across a problem that I cannot solve, I must have missed a piece of information.

My program is quite basic, I would like to create a volume so as not to lose the information retrieved each time the container is launched.

Here is my docker-compose

```
version: '3.3'
services:
    homework-logger:
        build: .
        ports:
            - '54321:1235'
        volumes:
            - ./app:/app
        image: 'cinabre/homework-logger:latest'
        networks:
            - homeworks

networks:
  homeworks:
   name: homeworks-logger
```

and here is my DockerFile

```
FROM debian:9
WORKDIR /app

RUN apt-get update -yq && apt-get install wget curl gnupg git apt-utils -yq && apt-get clean -y

RUN apt-get install python3 python3-pip -y

RUN git clone http://192.168.5.137:3300/Cinabre/Homework-Logger /app

VOLUME /app

RUN ls /app

RUN python3 -m pip install bottle beaker bottle-cork requests

CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

I did an "LS" in the container to see if the / app folder was empty: it is not

Any ideas?

thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Volumes are there to hold your application *data*, not its code.  You don't usually need the Dockerfile `VOLUME` directive and you should generally avoid it unless you understand exactly what it does.

In terms of workflow, it's commonplace to include the Dockerfile and similar Docker-related files in the source repository yourself.  Don't run `git clone` in the Dockerfile.  (Credential management is hard; building a non-default branch can be tricky; layer caching means Docker won't re-pull the branch if it's changed.)

For a straightforward application, you should be able to use a near-boilerplate Dockerfile:

```sh
FROM python:3.9  # unless you have a strong need to hand-install it
WORKDIR /app

# Install packages first.  Unless requirements.txt changes, Docker
# layer caching won't repeat this step.  Do not list out individual
# packages in the Dockerfile; list them in Python-standard setup.py
# or Pipfile.
COPY requirements.txt .
# ...in the "system" Python space, not a virtual environment.
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application in.
COPY . .

# Set the default command to run the container, and other metadata.
EXPOSE 1235
CMD ["python3", "main.py"]
```

In your application code you need to know where to store the data.  You might put this in an environment variable:

```py
import os
DATA_DIR = os.environ.get('DATA_DIR', '.')
with open(f"${DATA_DIR}/output.txt", "w") as f:
  ...
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` file, you can specify an alternate data directory and mount that into your container.  Do not mount a volume over the `/app` directory containing your application's source code.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  homework-logger:
    build: .
    image: 'cinabre/homework-logger:latest' # names the built image
    ports:
        - '54321:1235'
    environment:
        - DATA_DIR=/data # (consider putting this in the Dockerfile)
    volumes:
        - homework-data:/data # (could bind-mount `./data:/data` instead)
    # Use the automatic `networks: [default]`
volumes:
  homework-data:
```